# $X \times Y$ homeomorphic to $Z \times Y$ implies $X$ is homeomorphic to $Z$?

Tags: general-topology

True or false, if true, prove if false provide counterexample.

> If $X \times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Z \times Y$ (in the product topology) then $X$ is homeomorphic to $Z$.

Need help. I've been stuck on this for awhile. I think it's true but I can't prove it...

Comment: Standard counterexample: $X= \Bbb{R}, Y= \Bbb{R}^{\omega} , Z= \{ 0 \}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $X = \{0\}$, $Y = Z = \mathbb{N}$ each with discrete topology. Then we only have to see that there is a bijection between $X \times Y$ and $Z \times Y$ but there is no bijection between $X$ and $Z$. But this should be known.

Comment: So we use the discrete topology to ensure that any bijection is a homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, that was my idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a whole family of examples in the following way. Let $X$ be any space that is not homeomorphic to $X^{\Bbb N}$; familiar nice examples include $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology, $[0,1]$, $\Bbb Z$, and $\Bbb R$. Let $Y=Z=X^{\Bbb N}$. Then

$$X\times Y\cong X^{\Bbb N}\cong X^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}\cong Z\times Y\;,$$

but $X\not\cong Z$.

Comment: I know this is an old post but what if $Y=[0,1]$? Just wondering if there are any simple examples for $X$ and $Z$.