# Is it true that $X \times I \sim Y \times I \Longrightarrow X \sim Y$?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

The following question came to my mind:

> Let $I$ be the unit interval. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces such that $X \times I$ is homeomorphic to $Y \times I$. Does it follow that $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$?

It doesn't look so hard, but somehow I couldn't find a proof or counterexample.

If the answer turns out to be negative, I would be interested in what one should assume about $X$ and $Y$ to make the implication true.

Now reposted at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260953/is-it-true-that-x-times-i-sim-y-times-i-implies-x-sim-y).

Comment: Possibly related (or could be interesting): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1057907, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716804, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396608

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819743/x-times-y-homeomorphic-to-z-times-y-implies-x-is-homeomorphic-to-z?rq=1).

Comment: `It doesn't look so hard` I think the problem is **very** hard. There are counterexamples when you use $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $S^n$ instead of $I$. But the $I$ variant seems to be quite interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I skimmed through the threads you've posted and I would expect that there should exist some counterexample to my question.

Comment: Looks hard. I suggest you cross-post this on MO.

Comment: @Watson, yeah, I was going to do so but I forgot about it. I will do it now.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/260953/is-it-true-that-x-times-i-sim-y-times-i-implies-x-sim-y

Comment: This was the first problem of the Saint Petersburg Topology Olympiad! http://mathcenter.spb.ru/nikaan/olympiad/problemseng.pdf